# Return Observable<boolean> to a boolean value

Tags: angular

I am using angular 7

I created an Observable value that I want true/false from it. Here is my code in comment-block.component.ts file

```ts
public maxSequencevalue: Sequence;

public hasNextComment(): Observable<boolean> {
    const latestSequence = this.commentListDataService.commentList.latestSequence();

    return this.commentAcquireService.getUnreadList(this.postId, -1)
        .pipe(
            map((commentList) => {
                this.maxSequencevalue = commentList.list[0].sequence;
                if(latestSequence.value < this.maxSequencevalue.value) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            })
        );
}
```

How can I get a boolean, true/false value out of `this.hasNextComment()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get value from method which returns `Observable<boolean>`, you have to subscribe to this method.

For example:

```
this.hasNextComment().subscribe((val: boolean) => console.log(val)
```

You can write simpler your map method.

Instead of:

```
if(latestSequence.value < this.maxSequencevalue.value) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

use: `return latestSequence.value < this.maxSequencevalue.value`